# Which version of unix from a shell?

Tags: ksh, version

I recently started a new job, and was told that I need to log on (Via shell) to a particular unix system. I'm trying to figure out a few peculiarities with the system, but first I need to know what version of unix it is running. I could go and find a system admin, but that's a bit of a pain, as I don't actually know who maintains the system. How can I figure out using a shell (ksh) what version of unix I am actually using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To find the unix system type, host name, kernel version, etc execute this command:

```
uname -a
```

Comment: That did the trick! SunOS, no wonder I was finding stuff to be odd...

Comment: It's probably actually Solaris, but I'd rather not get into Sun's confusing versioning and naming scheme.